# How to filter columns from CSV file based on names of columns

Tags: perl, csv

I am using the CSV data like below. I don't want to use user and timestamp from csv file. I may add few columns or delete columns.

I didnt find the any suitable method in Text CSV. 
Please let me know if any method or module is available

```
UniqueId, Name, description, user,timestamp     
1,jana,testing,janardar,12-10-2018:00:
```

```
sub _filter_common_columns_from_csv{

    my $csvfile = shift;
    my $CSV = Text::CSV_XS->new(
                                {
                                    binary => 1,
                                    auto_diag => 3,
                                    allow_quotes => 0,
                                    eol => $/ 
                                });
    my $_columns ||= do {
    open(my $fh, '<', $csvfile) or die $!;
    my @cols = @{ $CSV->getline($fh) };
    close $fh or die $!;
    for (@cols) { s/^\s+//; s/\s+$//; }
        \@cols;
    };
    my @columns = @{ $_columns };     
    my %deleted;                        
    my @regexes = qw(user timestamp);
    foreach my $regex (@regexes) {
            foreach my $i (0 .. ($#columns - 1)) {
                    my $col = $columns[$i];
                       $deleted{$i} = $col if $col =~ /$regex/;
            }
    }

    my @wanted_columns = grep { !$deleted{$_} } 0 .. $#columns - 1;
    my $input_temp = "$ENV{HOME}/output/temp_test.csv";


    open my $tem, ">",$input_temp or die "$input_temp: $!";

    open(my $fh, '<', $csvfile) or die $!;

    while (my $row = $CSV->getline($fh)) {
           my @fields = @$row;
              $CSV->print($tem, [ @fields[@wanted_columns] ]) or $CSV->error_diag;
    }
    close $fh or die $!;
    close $tem or die $!;

    return $input_temp;
}
```

Comment: [Text::AutoCSV](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::AutoCSV) is one of my favorites for working with csv files. In particular read up on the `out_fields` option.

Comment: Re: "_I didnt find the any suitable method in Text CSV._" -- See under [getline_hr](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#getline_hr), where the docs give sample code for two ways to do this.

Answer (score 2):

See [getline_hr](https://metacpan.org/pod/Text::CSV#getline_hr)

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

use List::MoreUtils qw(any);
use Text::CSV;

my $file = shift @ARGV || die "Usage: $0 filename\n";

my @exclude_cols = qw(user timestamp);

my $csv = Text::CSV->new ( { binary => 1 } ) 
    or die "Cannot use CSV: ".Text::CSV->error_diag (); 

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my @cols  = @{ $csv->getline($fh) };

my @wanted_cols = grep { 
    my $name = $_; 
    not any { $name eq $_ } @exclude_cols;
} @cols;

my $row = {}; 
$csv->bind_columns (\@{$row}{@cols});

while ($csv->getline($fh)) {
    my @wanted_fields = @$row{ @wanted_cols };
    say "@wanted_fields";
}
```

The syntax `@$row{@wanted_cols}` is for a hash [slice](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices), which returns a list of values for the keys in `@wanted_cols` from the hashref `$row`.

Answer (score 0):

Actual example using Text::AutoCSV to remove given named columns from arbitrary CSV files like in your posted code (More complicated than the examples in the documentation for only writing specific columns):

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::AutoCSV qw/remove_accents/;

sub remove_columns {
  my ($infile, $outfile, $drop) = @_;
  my $csv = Text::AutoCSV->new(in_file => $infile, out_file => $outfile);
  # Normalize column names the same way that Text::AutoCSV does
  my %drops = map { my $h = remove_accents $_;
                    $h =~ s/[^[:alnum:]_]//gi;
                    $h = uc $h;
                    $h => 1 } @$drop;
  my @cols = grep { not exists $drops{$_} } $csv->get_fields_names;
  # Hack to avoid reading the file twice.
  $csv->{out_fields} = \@cols;
  $csv->write();
}

remove_columns "in.csv", "out.csv", [ "user", "timestamp" ];
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to modify your CSV in other ways, too, and if SQL would be convenient for those modifications, then consider using `DBD::CSV`.

You can then open a database handle on your CSV file, select the desired columns with a `SELECT` query, and write the results with `Text::CSV` or `Text::CSV_XS`.

For more details, see [the DBD::CSV documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::CSV) or e.g. [this simple wrapper script for querying CSV files](http://www.win.tue.nl/~rp/laquso-bin/csvsql).